# How do I deploy my node.js app to a server?

Tags: node.js, api

I have created a node server that scrapes through a certain website and then returns a nicely formatted json data. Everything works perfectly fine on my localhost. But now I want to upload it to a server and get a link that returns the json data (just like an api).

How do I do that?

Below is the code outline:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/', gotdata);

function gotdata(req, res){
    url = 'myurlhere';
    request(url, inside_request);

    function inside_request(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var title, date, permalink;
            var obj = { title : "", date : "", permalink : ""};
         // ALL MY CODES HERE
        res.send(obj);
        }
    }
}

app.listen('8081');
console.log('Visit http://localhost:8081/');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

OUTPUT from my **localhost:8081/**

[image]

Comment: Try Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: So, you wanna access from not localhost? Like actual remote server?

Comment: "How do I do that?" — What's wrong with using the same way that you run it on your local computer?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an nginx server instead if you have a public IP on the server where you want to deploy your API. 
Define a virtual host to your API from nginx configuration. 
Please follow the tutorial in the following link for virtual host creation

https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0